# Creating an executable python program that utilizes files from a directory and outputs them to another directory?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

Im trying to build a python executable program that takes in JSON files in one directory -> processes -> outputs them as CSVs to another directory.

I have already written out everything and the python script works fine when I run it in the terminal. But when I create a python executable program using pyinstaller and run it, no output csvs are created in the specified directory.
Is there a specific place I need to place my input and output directories for the script to recognize them? Is there something I need to do with the .spec file?

Answer (score 0):

Running executable (i named it as "**fake executable**") built with `pyinstaller`, your "**fake executable**" will be uncompress to other location, then execute the python script at that location ("**real executable**").

In your case, I think CSV file is saved base on location of "**real executable**". Then you should determine the location of "**fake executable**" to save CSV file.

Use this method on your main script to determine the location of your "fake executable":

```
def get_executable_dir():
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        return os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    elif __file__:
        return os.path.dirname(__file__)
    else:
        log.e(f"Could not detect executable location!")
        sys.exit()
```